# PHP login code error with mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql, scripting

I've been following a login system tutorial. You can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY08_fhcEC4). There are 2 parts of coding C# and PHP. The C# part is working fine but my PHP part returning error. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

    $servername = getenv('IP');
    $username = getenv('C9_USER');
    $passwordp = "";
    $database = "game_database";
    $dbport = 3306;

    // Create connection
    mysql_connect($servername, $username, $passwordp, $dbport)or die("Cant Connect to server");
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Cant connect to database");
    // Check connection


$Email = $_REQUEST["Email"];
$Password= $_REQUEST["Password"];

if (!$Email || !$Password){
    echo"Email or password must be used";
}
else{
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE Email = '"  . $Email ."'";
    $result_id = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Database Error");
    $Total = mysql_num_rows($result_id);
    if ($Total){
        $datas = @mysql_fetch_array($result_id);
        if (strcmp($Password, $datas["Password"])){
                    $sql2 = "SELECT Characters FROM users WHERE Email = '" . $Email ."'";
                    $result_id2 = @mysql_query($sql2) or die("Database Error!!!");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_id2)){
                        echo $row ["Characters"];
                        echo ":";
                        echo "Success";
                    }
        }
        else{
            echo "WrongPassword";
        }
        }else {
            echo "NameDoesNotExist";
        }
    }

?>
```

It seems the error comes from $result_id but I'm not sure?

Comment: I understand you are trying to do something with C#, but this question doesn't seem to be about C# at all, let alone Unity3D.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? This code is also open to SQL injections. Also you should suppress errors when debugging.

Comment: About SQL injection: Allow me to introduce you to the story of little [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Now, as for the problem that you noticed, it would help to know what the error was. Also, it would really help to have a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I get the error "Database Error" from the mysql_query in $result_id which comes from or die

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are true, the error is from `$result_id`, because your SQL statement has problem and there are extra stuff to fix.

You have put `users` table in two single quotes, it is wrong.

Your code is:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE Email = '"  . $Email ."'";
```

It should be with out quotes:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '"  . $Email ."'";
```

You have wrote:

```
if ($Total){
```

It should check how many users record found, typically it should find only 1 record and return 1, therefore change it to:

```
if ($Total == 1){
```

**Note1:**
But when this is said, it does not mean the code is perfect, you should further develop your code to fulfill nowadays requirement. I would suggest you think of password hashing, use mysqli or PDO in sted of mysql and input sensitization. I would suggest you look at this [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) it describes some of the things I mentioned.

**Note2:**
I was able to write you a total solution with mysqli/PDO etc, but I wanted only to point the errors I have catch so far in your code so you can learn from your mistakes and develop your self.

And in general read about security principles, check this [page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project).

Link1: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Link2: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Comment: when I register then login I get the error "Namedoesnotexist" from php script even though I have a table called users in game_database

Comment: check the edited answer, put Characters back as it was and check that Characters exist in the table of users.

Answer (score 0):

> This is another simple way where you can create user log in, it is
>   more secure than the one you have at the moment. And you should
>   protect your code from sql injections.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']) === true )
{
    require 'connection.php';

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
    {
        if( $email == $row['email'] && $password == $row['password'])
        {                         //use session to check if user is logged in
            if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) 
            {
                //you can set session of user's log in details
                //you can redirect to user profile
            } 
            else 
                //already log in, redirect to user profile
        }
        else 
            echo "Incorrect Email or Password.";
    }
    else
        echo "Incorrect Username or Password.";
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
else
{
    echo "Oops, something went wrong!";
?>
```